# Recibir y utilizar el HttpStatusCode de una petición POST en ANGULAR

Tags: angular

Estoy haciendo una **peticion POST** al servidor y me gustaría poder utilizar el **código de respuesta** para mostrar un mensaje o una alerta avisando si la petición se pudo realizar o no.
Estoy usando HttpClient y haciendo la solicitud de la forma

**return this.http.post(this.url+'experiencia/crear',data, {observe:'response'})**
(este código va en el servicio)

**this.agregar.agregarExperiencia(body).subscribe((body)=>{
console.log(body)})**
(este código va en el componente) *body es una variable tipo json que le envío*.

La petición se realiza de forma correcta y en la bsae de datos se agrega el item pero me gustaría poder tomar el código de estado de la respuesta para poder usarlo en el componente

Según entiendo con {observe:'response'} obtengo toda la respuesta pero no logro tomar el status ni el statustext.
La consola de chrome me muestra {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: 'OK',...

También me dice que hay un HttpErrorResponse xq la api retorna "El item se agregó correctamente" y me dice que no es un JSON válido, ¿no sé si eso tendrá algoq ue ver con mi problema?

En Resumen, me gustaría saber como podría tomar ese código y utilizarlo en el componente.
Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A la suscripción al observable de la petición se le puede pasar un objeto que contenga: `next` que es la función que se ejecutará si la petición fue exitosa (código 2xx) y `error` que se ejecutará si hay un error (4xx | 5xx).

```
.subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        console.log('la petición fue exitosa')
      }, 
      error: () =>{
        console.log('ocurrió un error al hacer la petición')
      }
    })
```

Hay otro problema que está del lado del front end y es que aunque la petición sea correcta el contenido no es el esperado, para eso en la petición se puede especificar que el tipo de respuesta es texto y no json.

```
return this.http.post(this.url+'experiencia/crear',data, {responseType: 'text'})
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. Era justo lo que precisaba. Agregué el {responseType: 'text'} y dejé de recibir el error en la consola y funcionó todo a la perfección.